# How to make the condition dynamic within Case Statement in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, conditional-statements

I'm working with the following code at the moment:

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat
        Select Case .List(.Value)
            Case "Region1": Region0_Select
            Case "Region2": Region1_Select
            Case "Region3": Region2_Select
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

The macro relates to a dropdown on an excel sheet.

Is there any way to base the condition on a cell value? i.e. IF the dropdown equals cell A1 instead of "Region1".

I tried using something with Range("A1").Value to no avail.

Comment: The Case criteria have to be either String or Numeric literals (ie constants).

Comment: Are there always 3 case conditions?  Would you be willing to use an IIF instead of Select Case?  (it might not look as nice)

Comment: There will be a constant amount of case conditions, but much more than 3. Around 40, so an IF would be possible but messy.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the values in worksheet ranges in your Case Statement.

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()
 Dim sDropDownVal As String

 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
   sDropDownVal = .Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat.List(.Value)
   Select Case sDropDownVal

      Case .Range("A1").Value
         Call Region0_Select

      Case .Range("B1").Value, .Range("B3").Value, .Range("B5").Value
         Call Region1_Select

      Case (.Range("C1").Value + 2) * 10
         Call Region2_Select

      Case Else
         '---your code if no conditions met
   End Select
 End With
End Sub
```

For more complex tests, you can use Select Case True to give you more flexibility in testing whether criteria has been met.

This code shows a few different tests.

```
Sub DropDown1_Change2()
 Dim sDropDownVal As String

 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
   sDropDownVal = .Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat.List(.Value)

   Select Case True

      Case sDropDownVal = .Range("A1").Value
         Call Region0_Select

      Case sDropDownVal >= .Range("B1").Value
         Call Region1_Select

      '--can evaluate more complex tests also
      Case sDropDownVal = .Range("C1").Value And _
            .Range("D1").Value = "Yes"
         Call Region2_Select

      Case Else
         '---your code to execute if no conditions met
   End Select
 End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to fully qualify your Range.
Below works for me:

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
    With ws.Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat
        Select Case .List(.Value)
            Case ws.Range("A1").Value: Region0_Select
            Case ws.Range("A2").Value: Region1_Select
            Case ws.Range("A3").Value: Region2_Select
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Or you can be explicit like this:

```
Case Is = ws.Range("A1").Value: Region0_Select
```

Also take note that something must be selected in the *Drop Down*.